# Rails - Grape validations error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-grape

I have problem while updating the application from Rails 4 to Rails 5.0.2
When I try I have this error:

```
/projects/tx/app/api/api_v2/validations.rb:3:in `<module:Validations>': uninitialized constant Grape::Validations::Validator (NameError)
    from /projects/tx/app/api/api_v2/validations.rb:2:in `<module:APIv2>'
    from /projects/tx/app/api/api_v2/validations.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /projects/tx/app/api/api_v2/deposits.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /projects/tx/app/api/api_v2/deposits.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Try to find solution for this but not success at all. Maybe Grape change some naming.
The code inside validations.rb seems like this:

```
module APIv2
  module Validations
    class Range < ::Grape::Validations::Validator

      def initialize(attrs, options, required, scope)
        @range    = options
        @required = required
        super
      end

      def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
        if (params[attr_name] || @required) && !@range.cover?(params[attr_name])
          raise Grape::Exceptions::Validation, param: @scope.full_name(attr_name), message: "must be in range: #{@range}"
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

File deposits.rb is like this:

```
require_relative 'validations'

module APIv2
  class Deposits < Grape::API
    helpers ::APIv2::NamedParams

    before { authenticate! }

    desc 'Get your deposits history.'
    params do
      use :auth
      optional :currency, type: String, values: Currency.all.map(&:code), desc: "Currency value contains  #{Currency.all.map(&:code).join(',')}"
      optional :limit, type: Integer, range: 1..100, default: 3, desc: "Set result limit."
      optional :state, type: String, values: Deposit::STATES.map(&:to_s)
    end
    get "/deposits" do
      deposits = current_user.deposits.limit(params[:limit]).recent
      deposits = deposits.with_currency(params[:currency]) if params[:currency]
      deposits = deposits.with_aasm_state(params[:state]) if params[:state].present?

      present deposits, with: APIv2::Entities::Deposit
    end

    desc 'Get details of specific deposit.'
    params do
      use :auth
      requires :txid
    end
    get "/deposit" do
      deposit = current_user.deposits.find_by(txid: params[:txid])
      raise DepositByTxidNotFoundError, params[:txid] unless deposit

      present deposit, with: APIv2::Entities::Deposit
    end

    desc 'Where to deposit. The address field could be empty when a new address is generating (e.g. for bitcoin), you should try again later in that case.'
    params do
      use :auth
      requires :currency, type: String, values: Currency.all.map(&:code), desc: "The account to which you want to deposit. Available values: #{Currency.all.map(&:code).join(', ')}"
    end
    get "/deposit_address" do
      current_user.ac(params[:currency]).payment_address.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Some versions from Gemfile: gem 'grape', '0.19.2' 
gem 'grape-entity', '0.6.1' 
gem 'grape-swagger', '0.27.1'

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Totic Still not, the problem persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  find the reason [here](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/v0.19.2/UPGRADING.md#changes-to-custom-validators), and you can find initial method signature [here](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/v0.19.2/lib/grape/validations/validators/base.rb#L14).

change **validations.rb**

```
module APIv2
  module Validations
    class Range < ::Grape::Validations::Validator

      def initialize(attrs, options, required, scope, opts = {})
        @range    = options
        @required = required
        super
      end

      def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
        if (params[attr_name] || @required) && !@range.cover?(params[attr_name])
          raise Grape::Exceptions::Validation, param: @scope.full_name(attr_name), message: "must be in range: #{@range}"
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```